# Correct object and syntax to pass miscellaneous meta-data to another method in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I would like to pass some meta-data to a method that posts `JSON` to a server. The meta data consists of various types including strings, `NSNumbers`, `Bools` and so forth.

My `JSON` post method works for the message.  I have also added a string argument that compiles.  My efforts to add array or dictionary objects do not work. Currently the method looks like this:

```
 func postMessageToWeb ( _ message : ChatMessage, _ meta: String = "") {
        //post to server
}
```

Here is how I am calling the method:

```
self.postMessageToWeb(ChatMessage(answer))
```

This compiles, however, when I try to include the string after the message, I get assorted compiler errors.  For example

`self.postMessageToWeb(ChatMessage(answer), meta: "test")` gives error:

Extraneous argument label 'meta:' in call

What is the syntax to send the meta data to the array?

BTW, I have also experimented with using other data types as arguments for the Post Method such as `[String: Any] = [] and dict=[:]` but get compiler errors.

Comment: According to the guidelines you are discouraged from omitting the parameter labels except the first one if the method name implies the parameter name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underscore `_` in front of a parameter in a method signature means that it should be called without a label. Therefore the proper way to call the method as defined would be:

```
self.postMessageToWeb(ChatMessage(answer), "test")
```

If you want to include the "meta" label (as per convention), define the function like so:

```
func postMessageToWeb(_ message: ChatMessage, meta: String = "") {...}
```

As vadian pointed out, the convention is to only use `_` on the first parameter, and only when the parameter name is implied by the method name (as in your case).

To accept parameters other than a `String`, you should use `AnyObject` instead of `Any` as I believe JSON serialization only works with object types. You should be able to pass `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSString` or `NSNumber` objects for serialization (or their compatible bridged Swift variants).

Comment: Thanks.  Got it to work and now understand things a bit better.

Comment: If I were to use AnyObject  in func postMessageToWeb ( _ message : ChatMessage, meta: AnyObject = "") , what would default be--instead of ""

Comment: @user1904273 You probably want to make it optional, which can default to `nil`. Otherwise you would have to give it a real object value. Try this: `func postMessageToWeb(_ message: ChatMessage, meta: AnyObject? = nil)` but be sure to check if it's nil or not inside the method.